# Jquery Increase and Decrease Zomming is not working

Tags: jquery

I am using Increase and decrease for zoom image but i want to show
decrease when user clicks the  image. When I tried this code; decrease is not working
..why?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    var cell = $('#pok');
    $('.increase').click(function(){
        cell.height(cell.height()+20);
        $(".title").html('<a href="#" class="decrease">Decrease</a>')
    });
    $('.decrease').click(function(){
        cell.height(cell.height()-20);
    });
});
</script>
<img src="/41.jpg"id="pok"class="increase"><span class="title"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for `dynamically created elements` like,

```
$(document).on('click','.decrease',function () {
    cell.height(cell.height() - 20);
});
```

Also Use `$(function(){` instead of `$(window).load(){` see [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5BF4W/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.click` with `.on`

```
$(window).load(function(){
var cell = $('#pok');
$('.increase').click(function(){
    cell.height(cell.height()+20);
 $(".title").html('<a href="#" class="decrease">Decrease</a>')
});
$('.decrease').on("click",function(){
    cell.height(cell.height()-20);
});

 });
```

Documentation from the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function

```
This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler)
```

Comment: that should be `on('click',`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that when you select elements with the class .decrease you get 0 elements because you attach it just when you click on the increase.

Change the ".decrease" selector for ".title" and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.increase').click(function(){
            var cell = $(this);
            cell.height(cell.height()+20);
            $(this).find(".title").html('<a href="#" class="decrease">Decrease</a>');
        });
        $('.decrease').click(function(){
            var cell = $(this).parent().find('.increase');
            cell.height(cell.height()-20);
        });
    });
</script>

<img src="/41.jpg"id="pok"class="increase"><span class="title"></span>
```